# How can i update values for all keys in nested object at once in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have object like below, in the below object i save the preferences as true/false 
now i want to update status for all at once either true/false for cases like checked all or un-checked all.

```
obj = {
    a:false,
    b:{
        c:{
            e:{
                f:false,
                g:true,
            },
            h:{
                i:false,
                j:true,
            }
        }
    },
    k:{
        l:false,
        m:false
    },
    n:true
}
```

I am thinking of using recursive function and i can access values for all keys with recursive function
but i need best approach to update state.

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive function will indeed do what you need, it could look like this:

```js
const obj = {
    a:false,
    b:{
        c:{
            e:{
                f:false,
                g:true,
            },
            h:{
                i:false,
                j:true,
            }
        }
    },
    k:{
        l:false,
        m:false
    },
    n:true
};

const setAllTo = (val, object) => Object.keys(object)
  .reduce((prev, curr) => ({
    ...prev,
    [curr]: typeof object[curr] === 'object' ?
      setAllTo(val, object[curr]) : val
  }), {})
  

const result = setAllTo(true, obj);

console.dir(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

For very deeps Arrays, the straight forward approach might get slow,
I thought of a way of doing it with string replace instead.

```js
const obj = {
    a:false,
    b:{
        c:{
            e:{
                f:false,
                g:true,
            },
            h:{
                i:false,
                j:true,
            }
        }
    },
    k:{
        l:false,
        m:false
    },
    n:true
};

function checkAll(obj,state = true) {
  const regex = state ? /true/gi : /false/gi;
  const changeTo = state ? 'false' : 'true';
  // the magic, using string replace to set all at once
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj).replace(regex, changeTo));
}

function uncheckAll(obj) {
  return checkAll(obj,false);
}

console.log(checkAll(obj));
console.log(uncheckAll(obj));
```

Can't tell you how performant it is, but I think the complexity will stay the same no matter how deep the arrays are.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure where you are stuck but this should do:

```
function setState(obj, value) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object') {
        setState(obj[prop], value);
      } else {
        obj[prop] = value;
      }
    }
  }
}

setState(obj, true);
```

Second argument for setState function sets the value for each property.
You can do it using loops but I think recursive example is more elegant.

What you need is to approach this problem in small steps:

1. First you pass the whole object
2. Then iterate through each property of that object
3. If object's property is also an object then you pass that particular
   property to setState function again and now that function works with
   even smaller portion of object

if property is not an object, then inside else statement we assume that it contains boolean value so we simply assign true value to it. So the function works until it reaches all the properties that contain boolean values.